# How can I know how much I paid for an iOS app?

Tags: ios-appstore

I'd like to know how much I paid for a specific iOS app. Is there any way to do this?

I realize that you can see your order history in iTunes, but its really hard to find a specific app using that interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get receipts by e-mail from Apple whenever I buy something in the iTunes store.  If you don't delete them they should still be there.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a receipt on your desktop or laptop you can click on 'Print' and then go down to PDF and find 'Save as Web Receipt' This will keep everything in one place all neat and tidy. :-)